# Other ways of writing \ in C#

Tags: c#, syntax

I have a bit of code that writes to a text document and i want to do this:

```
pathtxt.Text = pathtxt.Text + treeView1.SelectedNode.Text + "\";
```

but it thinks the \ is the start of a comment or something so how do i make it do a \ . Thank you

Comment: Just escape it: `"\\"`

Comment: Microsoft docs explain this, no need to make these kind of questions.

Comment: @kblok i searched online for an answer and didn't find one.must i not use stackoverflow. this is a qna site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of concatenating string (and escaping backslash), you can use `Path.Combine` like this:

```
pathtxt.Text = Path.Combine(pathtxt.Text,treeView1.SelectedNode.Text);
```

Comment: OP did not indicate they need a slash between `pathtxt.Text` and `treeView1.SelectedNode.Text`. Additionally this code does not add the trailing slash that OP *does* want.

Comment: @Quantic i have made totally wild guess by assuming that OP wants to construct a path and decided to offer him/her one indirect solution how to achieve that. If OP has that mysterious backslash in the middle (which I am, again, assuming) `Combine` will ignore it and create valid path. But, looks like my approach is deserving downvote. Well, I'll live with that.

Comment: Well I just saw that `pathtxt.Text` is reused, so my now deleted previous comment is ~irrelevant with the given code. The trailing slash is still important, IMO, and at least linking to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) would improve the quality of the answer so OP can avoid the pitfalls of the method (leading slashes on secondary paths break it). The downvote is because your answer literally doesn't answer the question, they want "to do this" and clearly show a trailing slash. Currently you have an XY Answer, the answer version of an XY Problem.

Comment: no this method worked and automaticly created the \.

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried

```
pathtxt.Text = pathtxt.Text + treeView1.SelectedNode.Text + @"\";
```

or

```
pathtxt.Text = pathtxt.Text + treeView1.SelectedNode.Text + "\\";
```

Answer (score 4):

`\` is used for escape sequences in text literals for C#. The compiler doesn't think it's the start of a comment: it thinks it's the start of an escape sequence. So you either need to use `"\\"` (i.e. the escape sequence for backslash) or `@"\"` (a verbatim string literal, which doesn't allow escape sequences).

[`Path.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) is a generally preferred way of creating paths from multiple segments, however.